# jquery selector to select a tags inside every li in the ul block

Tags: jquery

Here is an image which shows my ul block

[image]

every li is identical to the expanded li shown. How do I select all of these a tags within this ul ?

I tried using something like

```
 $('ul:has(li) > a')
```

but that does not seem right. Also I need to target the ul by its Id. Any help with this appreciated. Thanks ,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try the following:

```
 $('#sliding-navigation > li.sliding-element > a')
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#sliding-navigation li a') // selects all a's in ul, would be the same as doing $('#sliding-navigation a')
```

Or if the `ul` has more levels and you only want it to apply to the first level only:

```
$('#sliding-navigation > li > a')
```

**EDIT**

Btw an `img` tag in an `ul` tag doesn't look right.

Comment: By removing the first `ul` you can speed up the selector.

Answer (score 0):

You may try with `$('ul li a')` this shoul work fine.